# Unit test: using the proper terminology for mocking/stubbing

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, stubbing

After fundamental changes on my project system architecture, I find myself in a situation where I would need to create "*fake*" implementation in order to test some functionality that used to be public like the following:

```
/**
* Display the template linked to the page. 
*
* @param $newSmarty Smarty object to use to display the template.
*
* @param $parameters associative Array containing the values to pass to the template.
*       The key is the name of the variable in the template and the value is the value of the variable.
*
* @param $account child class in the AccountManager hierarchy
*
* @param $partialview String name of the partial view we are working on
*/
protected function displayPageTemplateSmarty(Smarty &$newSmarty, array $parameters = array(), AccountManager $account = NULL, string $partialview = "")
{
     $this->smarty = $newSmarty;

if (is_file(
    realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/../../" . 
    Session::getInstance()->getCurrentDomain() . "/view/" . (
        !empty($partialview) ? 
        "partial_view/" . $partialview :
        str_replace(
            array(".html", "/"), 
            array(".tpl", ""), 
            Session::getInstance()->getActivePage()
        )
    )
)) {

    $this->smarty->assign(
        'activeLanguage', 
        Session::getInstance()->getActiveLanguage()
    );

    $this->smarty->assign('domain', Session::getInstance()->getCurrentDomain());

    $this->smarty->assign(
        'languages', 
        Languagecontroller::$supportedLanguages
    );

    $this->smarty->assign(
        'title',
        Languagecontroller::getFieldTranslation('PAGE_TITLE', '')
    );

    $this->smarty->assign_by_ref('PageController', $this);

    $htmlTagBuilder = HTMLTagBuilder::getInstance();

    $languageController = LanguageController::getInstance();

    $this->smarty->assign_by_ref('htmlTagBuilder', $htmlTagBuilder);
    $this->smarty->assign_by_ref('languageController', $languageController);

    if (!is_null($account)) {

        $this->smarty->assign_by_ref('userAccount', $account);
    }

    if (!is_null($this->menuGenerator)) {

        $this->smarty->assign_by_ref('menuGenerator', $this->menuGenerator);
    }

    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {

        $this->smarty->assign($key, $value);    
    }

    $this->smarty->display((!empty($partialview) ? 
        "partial_view/" . $partialview : 
         str_replace(
            array(".html", "/"), 
            array(".tpl", ""), 
            Session::getInstance()->getActivePage()
        )
    ));
}
}
```

In this case, the `PageController` class used to be called directly in controllers, but is now an abstract class extended by the controllers and my unit tests can no longer access the method.

I also have methods like this one in my new session wrapper class that can only be used in very specific context and for which I really need to create fake page implementation to test them.

```
/**
* Add or update an entry to the page session array.
*
* Note: can only be updated by the PageController.
*
* @param $key String Key in the session array.
*   Will not be added if the key is not a string.
*
* @param $value The value to be added to the session array.
*
* @return Boolean
*/
public function updatePageSession(string $key, $value)
{
    $trace = debug_backtrace();

    $updated = false;

    if (isset($trace[1]) and 
        isset($trace[1]['class']) and
        $trace[1]['class'] === 'PageController'
    ) {

        $this->pageSession[$key] = $value;

        $updated = true;
    }

    return $updated;
}
```

Even though I read a few article, it is still quite unclear in my mind if those fake classes should be considered as "*stub*" or a "*mock*" (or even "*fake*", "*dummy*" and so on).

I really need to use the proper terminology since my boss is expecting me (in a close future) to delegate most of my workload with oversea developers.

How would you call those fake class implementation created solely for testing purpose in order to be self-explanatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gerard Meszaros explains the terminology of dummies, stubs, spies, mocks, and fakes [here](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html).

You can find examples from the PHP world [here](https://thephp.cc/dates/2015/10/international-php-conference/the-fall-guy).

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian. Since I extend the `PageController` to override the protected method and inject data, that would be stubbing. 

Considering that our main software (100% developed in Canada) doesn't have a single unit test, I should probably stick to a single appellation, for the sake of simplicity, when I'll vulgarize my expectations to the Moroccans developers my boss hired...